# Show project wide TypeScript problems/errors in webstorm

Tags: typescript, webstorm, visual-studio-code

Is there any way to make Webstorm continuously report all typescript errors project wide without opening all the files? For performance reasons I would like it done using the language service and not by a task running tsc.

I know Webstorm shows all problems in Dart projects using the Dart analysis server which I think is similar to the Typescript language service. So basically I am looking for a way to make Webstorm (or vscode) work the same way for TypeScript as it does for Dart projects with regards to reporting project wide errors.

Edit 2016-09-09:

A small example in Webstorm:

- File > New Project > Empty project
- Configure Webstorm > Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > TypeScript
- Check Use TypeScript Service (experimental)
- Check Enable TypeScript Compiler
- Check Track Changes
- Scope: Project Files
- Select Set Options Manually
- Command line options: --noEmit

Add these files:

test1.ts

```
export const foo:number = 5;
```

test2.ts

```
import {foo} from './test1';
const bar:string = foo;
```

- Close all documents and quit Webstorm.
- Restart Webstorm.
- Open the file test1.ts.
- Check "Current Errors" and "Project Errors" panes, they are both blank.
- Press "Compile all" button.
- Current Errors: blank (why?)
- Project Errors: test2.ts > Error:(3, 7) TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Now change the contents of test1.ts to this:

```
export const foo:string = "";
```

Save test1.ts.

- Both "Current Errors" and "Project Errors" are the same as before.
- Here I would expect the panes to be cleared since the error in test2.ts is fixed, but since test2.ts  is not open in the editor it does not seem to update.
- Press compile all button.
- Now both "Current Errors" and "Project Errors" are cleared.

Comment: disable option "Check Use TypeScript Service (experimental)". The part of integration shows only 'current errors'

Answer (score 4):

On Webstorm, the `Typescript -> Current Errors` tab displays project wide errors 'live'

Introduce or fix an error and the result will appear in that tab.

Typescript preferences must correctly be set; WS is using the project tsconfig.json in the example below. A 'Compile All' must be run from that tab at least once (to build the errors cache, I guess)

[image]

Comment: I already tried this before but cannot get it to work. Please see the example I added in the question. Does this example work in your setup?

Comment: Where is the Typescript Tab ? How do I open it ?

Comment: Looking at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/typescript-compiler-tool-window.html, it seems like you need to Compile TS in the IDE for that window to show up.