# How to get VSCode to show TypeScript errors for files *not* open in the editor?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, create-react-app

In my `create-react-app@2.1.8` TypeScript/React app, TS compiler errors are only shown in the Problems pane for files I have open in the VS Code editor.  As a result I sometimes don't catch errors until I actually run the app.

How can I get TypeScript to automatically check for compiler errors in all code files as soon as I open the workspace, or when I save changes to a file?

I've tried adding `"watch": "tsc --watch"` as a script in `package.json` and then doing `npm run-script watch` in an integrated terminal pane, but this has two problems:

- errors show up in the terminal pane but don't populate the Problems pane in VSCode
- I have to manually run it, instead of it automatically starting when the workspace loads

Is there a better solution?

BTW, this is the same question as [Show project wide TypeScript problems/errors in webstorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401231/show-project-wide-typescript-problems-errors-in-webstorm), but about Visual Studio Code instead of webstorm.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As of November 2019, unfortunately this isn't supported by VS Code out of the box. See https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13953.

The best workaround that I could find is to add a task to tasks.json that will run `tsc --watch`, and configure it to run when the workspace or folder is opened.

Below is a sample config for tasks.json. Note that "www" in the snippet below refers to the folder with `tsconfig.json` that you want to check. Replace it with the name of your own folder, relative to the root of your workspace.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "tsc watch",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc",
            "isBackground": true,
            "args": ["--watch", "--noEmit", "--project", "www"],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "never",
                "echo": false,
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "dedicated"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch",
            "runOptions": {
                "runOn": "folderOpen"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that auto-run tasks don't seem to be enabled by default. To opt into auto-run tasks, follow the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58866185/126352

This solution was adapted from [@molinx](https://github.com/molinx)'s answer in the GitHub issue linked above, and it was improved thanks to [@kumar303](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729860/kumar303)'s comment below.

Comment: Version 1.30 added `"runOn": "folderOpen"` https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_30#_run-on-folder-open

Comment: @kumar303, this is a useful improvement!  I updated my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: was this functionality working previously and just got ousted by the new update?

Comment: I needed to change tasks slightly to make it work in Windows
`"command": "call"`

and the path to tsc in args like
`"args": ["node_modules/.bin/tsc", "--watch", "--noEmit", "--project", "www"],`

Answer (score 118):

As of *24.10.2023* There is an experimental feature in generally available [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) to enable project wide problem reporting. Add the following to your `settings.json`:

```
"typescript.tsserver.experimental.enableProjectDiagnostics": true
```

It is still an **experimental** feature (after few years of neglect), so it can be both overwhelming and underwhelming at the same time. Good thing is that it apparently works with other languages as well and respects your config files.

People [report](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/13953#issuecomment-1221141438) that this option scans the contents of `node_modules` even thought it is in `exclude` list, but adding 'skipLibCheck' [helps](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/13953#issuecomment-1632148288)

Watch this [space](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/13953).

Comment: The configuration which worked for me is   `"typescript.tsserver.experimental.enableProjectDiagnostics": true`. The team is actively working on this.

Comment: @DawsonB thanks you for the information, I've updated the ticket

Comment: I added this setting, restart VS Code but it's not showing any problems? (though I have some)

Comment: You can also just open the settings in the VSCode UI and search for "experimental typescript" and the Enable Project Diagnostics setting showing will show up. After clicking on the checkbox, it started worked for me.

Comment: It is still an experimental feature 2nd June 2022

Comment: @Ivandez yes, still experimental, still works, has some issue, but apparently works.

Comment: Any idea if there's a way to get this to work with eslint?

Comment:  Still works in August 2023. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to scan the `node_modules` directory (even though this is excluded in jsconfig.json) so it's pretty much unusable for JS Doc projects.

Comment: @Marc try using [skipLibCheck](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#skipLibCheck) flag in `compilerOptions`

Comment: I've been looking for a way to see all of these error in vscode for a while!  This worked like a charm.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you get typescript errors from bad reference because of you dont have opened that references file/module too.
You have to go to Options->TextEditor->Javascript/typescript -> Project ->
and uncheck Ignore visual studio solution files.

Have a good day;

Answer (score 1):

A very similar answer than the other that was sent here but I bit different and worked great for me.

1. Add this line to your `.vscode/settings.json` file:

```json
"eslint.lintTask.enable": true
```

1. Add this task or create the file if it not exists on `.vscode/tasks.json` with:

```js
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "npm",
      "problemMatcher": ["$eslint-stylish"],
      "label": "eslint: lint whole folder",
      "script": "lint",
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "never",
        "panel": "new"
      },
      "runOptions": { "runOn": "folderOpen" },
      "detail": "Run eslint for all files on the workspace folder",
      "options": {
        "configFile": ".eslintrc.js",
        "ignorePath": ".eslintignore"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

PS.: `problemMatcher` is what makes the 'magic' on the problems tab.