# What does "on folder open" mean in VSCode's "run on folder open" tasks?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

VSCode added a feature last year that will [auto-run a task "on folder open"](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_30#_run-on-folder-open).  But what does "on folder open" mean when using workspaces?

Specifically, if you open a workspace, will `"runOn": "folderOpen"` tasks run? If so, how?

I'm asking because I configured a task to be auto-run, but it's not running when I open the workspace.  (The task runs correctly when triggered manually.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"On folder open" tasks *will* run when you open a workspace, just like when you use the "Open Folder..." link when opening a non-workspace folder.

However, there's an additional step required: you need to opt into auto-run tasks. I figured this out via subtle hint in the documentation which said this:

> everyone who allows tasks to be run automatically

That made me wonder how to enable tasks to run automatically. It turns out there's a configuration change you need to make, as follows:

1. Open the command palette (SHIFT+CMD+P) and choose "Tasks: Manage Automatic Tasks in Folder"
   [image]
2. Choose "Allow Automatic Tasks in Folder"
   [image]
3. Now close and re-open the workspace, and on-folder-open tasks will run as expected.

Frustratingly, this setting is not present in the usual JSON settings files, which means that it won't show up in the search of Settings.
[image]

This made me waste a bunch of time trying to find this setting, which is why I'm posting a Q&A pair here to help the next victim of this problem.

UPDATE: I also suggested that VSCode add this to Settings. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/64618#issuecomment-554072124

If you run the task manually first, you might see a reminder/toast message that allows you to give the permission to `"runOn": "folderOpen"`:
[image: VSCode task with runOn:folderOpen, after being run once manually, prompts you to give permission]

Comment: I was looking at the settings.json as well. Thanks!

Comment: Does someone know what is the corresponding `.vscode/settings.json` key for this feature?

Answer (score 2):

The mentioned [issue 64618](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/64618) is now closed, for VSCode 1.70 (July 2022), with [PR 154171](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/154171)

> ### add allow automatic tasks setting
>
> New setting `task.allowAutomaticTasks.on`' with values:
>
> - `Always`/`auto`: Prompt for permission for each folder
> - `Never`/`off`: Enable automatic tasks in the folder.

It is available today in [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).