# How to detect all Typescript and ESLint errors in NextJS project, not just in opened files?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, compiler-errors, next.js, eslint

I am working on a NextJS project and I want to see the errors and warnings from all the project, not just from opened files.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming your using vscode. There is an experimental feature which is described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60116499/15384103) which can enable project wide checks:

```
"typescript.tsserver.experimental.enableProjectDiagnostics": true
```

Comment: That's right, I am using VSCode! Great, it works! Thanks!